# How to get user google account data, in redirect mode after redirecting to login uri (Sign in with google)?

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth

I am having "sign in with google" option. On clicking, I am being redirected to google accounts page (UX-Mode: redirect) where it displays google accounts. After clicking the account I needed, it gets back to the login_uri link which is being mentioned. I want to get the google account data as JWT token. How to do it?

```
<div id="g_id_onload" 
                    data-client_id="XXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                    data-ux_mode="redirect"
                    data-login_uri="http://localhost:8080/XXXX" 
                    data-callback="handleCredentialResponse">
                    </div>
                    <div class="g_id_signin signup_adj" data-type="standard" id="gsignin"></div>
```

The above code the redirect mode code. since I use login uri, it takes precedence and data-callback doesn't work. The main thing is, I want to use redirect mode and also want to get the google account data i click on as JWT token.

Answer (score 0):

With "redirect" assigned to 'data-ux_mode', the 'data-callback' is ignored and the 'data-login_uri' becomes a required parameter. Changing 'data-ux_mode' to the default "popup" value will activate the 'data-callback' again.

More info in the official documentaion:
https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#data-login_uri